# Como crear una ruta dinámica , añadir props a rutas y agregarlas vuex vuejs

Tags: vue.js, rutas, router, props

Tengo un array con personajes y el cual tiene un campo **name** por el cual quiero mostrar todos los **name** de los personajes y que cuando se haga clic me lleve a todos los datos de ese personaje, pero no quiero crear muchos componentes.
Estoy probando con rutas dinámicas. necesito agregar el **name** que me llega por pros a la vista **Mostrar.vue**.

**index.js**

```
 actions: {
   async getCharacters({commit}){
     try {
       const response = await fetch('https://swapi.dev/api/people/?page=1')
       const name = this.$route.params.name; 
       const data = await response(name)
       console.log(data.results)
```

**home.vue**  es donde llamo al estado de **vuex** y llamo al componente **Card** dándole **props** **character**

```
<template><div class="home">
<Personajes />
 <button @click="sortaltura()">Ordenar por altura</button>
<button @click="sortnombre()">Ordenar por Alfabeticamente</button>
<div v-for="character in characters" :key="character.name">

  <Card :character ="character"/></div>
```

**router.js** le añadido **props true**

```
const routes = [
  {
    path: "/",
    name: "Home",
    component: Home,
  },


  {
    path: "/personaje/:name",
   name: "personaje",
   props: true,
  component: Mostrar,
  }
```

**Mostrar.vue** En esta vista es donde quiero implementar a mi llamada **vuex** el **name** que me llega por **props**

```
import { computed, onMounted } from "vue";
import { useStore } from "vuex";
 export default {
 props:['name'],
 created(){
 console.log(this.name)},
setup() {
const store = useStore();
const characters = computed(() => {
  return store.state.characters;
});
onMounted(() => {
  store.dispatch("getCharacters");
});

return {
  characters,  
};},
```

**CardPersonajes.vue** recojo con **props** **character** desde home

```
<template>
 <router-link :to="{name:'personaje' , params: {name: 
character.name}}">
   {{character.name}}
</router-link>
```

```
props:{
 character:{
     type:Object,
 },
```

Comment: He cambiado lo de personaje  el error me dice : vue-router.esm-bundler.js?6c02:72 [Vue Router warn]: No match found for location with path "{name:'personaje' , params: {name: character.name}}

Comment: ¿Por qué estás cargando el componente Home en la ruta personaje? No sería otro componente ahí?

Comment: Por probrar  en Home es donde tengo el v-for.

Comment: Cuando vas a pasar un objeto, como en este caso  `to="{name:'personaje' , params: {name : character.name}}"`, tienes que hacer un v-bind. Prueba con `:to="{name:'personaje' , params: {name : character.name}}"`. Nota los dos puntos antes de `to`, de otra forma lo toma como un string literal

Comment: Los dos puntos son un atajo para v-bind https://vuejs.org/api/built-in-directives.html#v-bind

Comment: Si los puse he realizado un cambio porque sin una vista card no se iba visualizar pero aun así cuando hago clic me dice que la propiedad name no esta definida el error esta en el routelink.

Comment: ya casi lo tengo, lo que me falta es agregar el props de rutas name a la  llamada de vuex de la vista Mostrar.vue

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135999/discussion-between-daniel-gonzalez-garrido-and-porloscerros-).